# Service-based design on a jboss server

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am currently looking for the best option to use a service-paradigm in a jboss server. OSGi is no longer supported and SPI works...oddly...in jboss so what else is there?

To give you a little bit of perspective, we have an ear file that contains:

- lib/

  - jarThatUsesSPI.jar
- MyEJB.jar
- MyWebInterface.war

  - lib/

    - someOtherDependency.jar

For MyEJB.jar:

- it can see the classes inside jarThatUsesSPI.jar
- the SPI works as in, everything is detected as it should be

For the MyWebInterface.war:

- it can see the classes inside jarThatUsesSPI.jar
- the SPI **does not work**, nothing is automatically detected.

If MyEJB approaches the spi jar first and initializes the SPI stuff -basically store the SPI results in memory in a singleton- and the web interface **then** requests that instance, it will see the same instance **with** the SPI loaded instances. So we are sure that the war and the parent ear file are looking at the same class with the same classloader, the same instances etc, except the SPI stuff does not work if you run it in the web interface first...

Due to this fragile SPI behavior and the non-support for OSGi, I'm curious to see what JBoss offers as an alternative, but I can't seem to find any...

Comment: One alternative for modularize an aplication in JBoss/Wildfly is JBoss Modules, take a look in this article http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/ModularizedJavaWithJBossModules

Comment: Modularity is not the problem, the lack of a service layer is. The articles states "It is minimal: there is no services layer, or any other higher level functions that OSGi provides. It does exactly one thing, and it does it well." That's awesome...but then what do you need to do if you **do** want a service layer on top of jboss modules? Is there a separate services project that works well on top of jboss modules?

Comment: JBoss provides JBoss Modules Service Loader API, but it is **not** recommended to use this API. You can use service provider interface (SPI) in their modules to add support to the service layer. If you examine some modules in jboss like `org.apache.xerces` this provide some services eg `javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory`.  Take a look in this thread https://developer.jboss.org/thread/171009?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: If you want full support for OSGi in jboss 7, the solution is to use JBoss Fuse (jboss.org/products/fuse/overview).